# Does Rust guarantee that elements of a Vec smaller than a word size will be tightly packed?

Tags: rust

How much space the *contents* of a `Vec<u16>` takes? With, say, 1000 elements. Is there a way to verify this with a test program?

Is this guaranteed to be the same as `&[u16]`? (I think it would make no sense to not be, since the conversion is cheap)

Also `Vec[u8]`, `&[u8]`, etc.

([`std::mem::size_of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) returns the static size of the type, not of its contents)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.**

The representation of the contents of a vector is the same as that of a slice, which is the same as that of a fixed-size array. Thus you may compare `std::mem::size_of::<[u16, 1]>()` and `std::mem::size_of::<[u16, 10]>()` and see that they always differ by a factor of ten. ([Citation: this code](http://is.gd/9rw3rC).)

Rust uses byte indexing, so `u8` takes one byte, `u16` takes two bytes, `u32` takes four bytes and `u64` takes eight bytes. `bool` also takes one byte; there are seven wasted bits per byte (hence types like the currently unstable [`BitVec`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BitVec.html)).

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the capacity and the contents do have a difference in size. That is, more space may be allocated than is currently used.